# Use 7-Zip to Compress folders within a directory and then delete the source folder used to create the .zip file

Tags: batch-file, compression, backup, scheduled-tasks, 7zip

I need to run a script to compress all folders within a folder that is 2 levels within a directory structure. I want the script to compress all folders within the log folder and then delete the original folder, thus saving loads on space. To illustrate the folders I wish to compress, see below:

Drive Location-->machinename-->logtype-->folders_i_want_to_compress

Within folder 2 there are folders with dates in the format yyyymmdd and it is these that I wish to compress as zip files.

I cannot work out how to create a script to do this but I did find a similar script here:[7-Zip compress files within a folder then delete files](https://superuser.com/questions/629035/7zip-compress-the-contents-of-each-folder-in-a-directory)

... that looks like this:

```
REM Usage: ZipFilesRecursively.bat "C:\My Files"
for /R "%~f1" %%F in (*) do (
    7z a -mx9 "%%~dpnxF.7z" "%%F"
    if exist "%%~dpnxF.7z" del "%%F"
)
```

But this is only for files. I cannot work how to change this so that it works for folders rather than files although I believe the start of it would be to use for with the /D switch rather than the /R.

As the path to the folders is based partly on the machine name, I need to feed this into the script, so I was planning on using a call from another batch file to then run the compression/deletion script.

The call script will look something like this

```
Call zipdeletetest4 machinename1
Call zipdeletetest4 machinename2    
Call zipdeletetest4 machinename3
Call zipdeletetest4 machinename4
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I eventually managed to get the compression part to work using ... `for /d %%x in ("E:\location\machinename\Logs\*.*") do start "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" /b /low /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%x.zip" "%%x\"`
But I just cannot work out how to then get the original folders deleted and just leave the zip files. I have tried a number of different lines but can't get this to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually went for

```
REM compress folders to zips
for /d %%x in ("C:\Logs\*.*") do start "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" /b /low /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%x.zip" "%%x\"

REM delete the original folders used to create zips
for /d %%F in ("C:\Logs\*") do rd /s /q "%%F"
```

Comment: Downvote as this solution is not only awkward but dangerous. You don't even check if a folder was compressed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using 7zip for command line, you should be able to use the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /d %%a in (*) do (7za a -tzip %%~na.zip "%%a")
for /d %%a in (*) do (if exist "%%a\" del "%%a")
pause
```

To use it, whack the batch file in the 'logtype' folder you mentioned, and run it.

Comment: Thanks for that... I've submitted the final solution as the answer the worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Command sets are the right things to perform such tasks correctly.

```
command && command_OK || command_Fail
```

`command_OK` will be executed only if `command` finished successfully and `command_Fail` will be executed in case of error. Typical use of this pattern:

```
call %archiver% %file% && (del %file%) || (exit /b 1)
```

But in this very case you won't need any additional commands. Luckily 7zip features wonderful `-sdel` option which does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I use for folders.

```
@echo off
for /D %%d in (*) do (
7z a t -mx9 -t7z -y "%%~nd.7z" "%%~fd" 
if exist "%%~nd.7z" rmdir /s /q "%%~fd"
else
echo The file "%%~fd" DOES NOT exist
pause
)
```